# ArrayList with multiple Generic types?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have this bugging problem I cannot figure out. I have this exercise:

> Complete the following generic Pair class, so that execution of the
>   program gives the indicated output. Do not change main.

```
class Pair ... {   ...  }

 class GenericPairTest {        
 public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Pair<String,Integer> phoneNumber = new Pair<>("Bill's number", 1324);   
        System.out.println(phoneNumber);

           Pair<Double,Double> point = new Pair<>(3.14, 2.32);      
       System.out.println(point);   
     } 
 }
```

The output is suposed to be like that:

Bill's number 1324

3.14  2.32`

I tried doing this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Pair <T,U> {

    ArrayList<T,U> newList = new ArrayList<>();

  Pair(T inT, U inU){
    newList.add(inT,inU);
  }

}

class GenericPairTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Pair<String,Integer> phoneNumber = 
            new Pair<>("Bill's number", 1324);  
        System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        Pair<Double,Double> point = 
            new Pair<>(3.14, 2.32);
        System.out.println(point);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: When you say "doesn't work :(" - What do you mean? Compilation error? Logical error? This will help people helping you better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need a list? You just need to store the two objects:

```
class Pair <T,U> {
    private T _t;
    private U _u;

    public Pair(T t, U u) {
        _t = t;
        _u = u;

    public String toString() {
        return _t + " " + _u;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then why is he creating an arraylist in the main? :(
Isn't the syntax "class<type> name = new class<>();" used to create lists?

Comment: Who creates arraylist? Where?

Comment: I get confused by this bit `Pair<String,Integer> phoneNumber = new Pair<>("Bill's number", 1324);`

Comment: Ohhhhhhh! It's just stating that we create a new Pair class and pass in as T a String and as U an Integer, call this instance "phoneNymber" and use new to create a reference, and put Bill's number as String and 1324 as Integer :D isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `ArrayList` in your `Pair` class.

Just keep the two values as two generic members.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for this I think:

```
ArrayList<Pair<T,U>>
```

but I think you should create an internal `Pair` class which might look something like this:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    private T left;
    private U right;
    // getters/setters + constructor for them
}
```

You can use a `Map` as well like the others pointed out but you don't need an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with ArrayList, but since your pair always holds exactly two objects, it really doesn't need to store them in a list. Just use two fields:

```
class Pair<T,U> {
    final T t;
    final U u;

    Pair(T t, U u) {
        this.t = t;
        this.u = u;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return t + " " + u;
    }
}
```

The way you're using the ArrayList there is very suggestive of a Map. For example, you could write:

```
Map<T,U> map = new HashMap<>();
Pair(T t, U u) {
    map.put(t, u);
}
```

But since a map can hold any number of key-value pairs, it is not really the right structure to use for storing a single pair.

Answer (score 1):

If your case, it would be enough to remember the pairs in the `Pair` class, and not have an internal `ArrayList` for that.

After that, externally, you can include `Pair`s in list.

```
final List<Pair<T,U>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, sorry to say this, but you're missing some very basic OOP skills here.